# Terminology for maximize/minimize choice

Tags: optimization, terminology

I'm writing optimization software where the user needs to decide whether they want to minimize or maximize the value the objective function (where the output will contain many putative optimal values). I'm looking for terminology. to name the option the user is presented with... something like "direction", "objective", "target", "orientation", or the clunky "maxOrMin". I suspect there's a single word that's mathematical, but not too esoteric.

The alternative is to name the option by one of the choices, and it can be true or false (e.g. maximize=False). The problem with this I want to force the user to pick one and not rely on the default value. This works because there are only two choices, maximize or minimize. But perhaps in the future I may want more choices, e.g., when the objective is qualitative.

Any suggestions on what the term should be? I'm leaning towards "objective".

Answer (score 0):

just build the function to minimise and trust the user to be clever to figure out maximizing f is same as minimising -f and call it **minimise**, else why does it matter if it comes with a manual? what about '**optimize**'?

Comment: Users will give me a file with their raw data from which I build the model. Either I force them to edit their data if it has the wrong sign, or they tell me how to interpret their values.

Answer (score 0):

For objective functions with a reward or utility type this is called maximize process.
For the case where objective functions related to a cost this is called minimize process.
So min or max choices might not be a bad idea after all.